# Category theory for describing systems?

Tags: reference-request, category-theory

In Rosetta Stone quantum description is interpreted from the category theory point of view. Systems (Hilbert spaces of wave functions) are objects and processes (linear operators) are arrows.

But the interpretation as state sets being objects and processes being arrows might be much wider and applicable to a wider class of systems, not only quantum. What can I read about this direction?

Or any other interpretations used to describe systems in general with the help of category theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start from [this](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0808.1032v1) and then search in its bibliography.

Comment: The better link is http://arxiv.org/abs/0905.3010 --- the later article of the author, included in the book where the rosetta stone was published.